# How to render HTML template?

Tags: python, django

I am looking at this method(from the book written by Antonio Mele)

```
def post_list(request):
  posts = Post.published.all()
  return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'posts': posts})
```

The OP said that we will create HTML templates to render the data generated
by the views.I do not understand this.This is the blog folder ls output

```
~/mysite/blog$ ls
admin.py  apps.py  __init__.py  migrations  models.py  __pycache__  tests.py  views.py
```

This is what views looks like

```
cat views.py 
from django.shortcuts import render
```

I can not grasp link between the post and views.py in this example.

Comment: Please modify your question based on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It might be a good idea to work through the [official django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) before you start Django By Example. It will take you through the basic concepts of models, views and templates.

Comment: Also, `post_list` should be in `views.py`, but it appears to be missing when you run `cat views.py`.

Comment: @Alasdair ok,will take a look,thnks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you post some data on the respective url, the code in view.py and in post method will run. Have a glance on the following snippet:

```
def post_list(request):          # http://127.0.0.1:8000/myurl
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # process the posted data if you wish to by
        # posted_data = request.data
        posts = Post.published.all()
        return render(request,'blog/post/list.html',{'posts': posts})
```

In above case you have to store the html template file in template/app_name/html_file.html directory. So that when your post method executes, it will return that html_file.html file with adding context to it as shown below:

```
context = {"posts": posts}
            return render(request, "video_response.html", context)
```

You have to add {{ posts }} in your html_file.html to get that data rendered in post method of views.py